# Script to place template onto webpage as user

Tags: python-2.7, browser, scripting

I'm trying to create a Python script that would allow me to place a template in two text boxes on a webpage with a unique keyboard command; something similar to Keepass' autotype feature but faster.

```
'''
Created on Jan 26, 2016

@author: emoore
'''
Print("Subject:")
Print("Problem Description:"
Print("Network Impact:")
Print("When did this issue begin:")
Print("Next actions for troubleshooting:")
Print("Current Network Impact:")
Print("Date of next follow up:")
```

Comment: Come on man! Tell us what have you tried?

Comment: Added what code I know.

Comment: You know not enough to start thinking about this kind of script.

Comment: Better use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) on Windows or `AutoKey` on Linux

Comment: Thanks furas!! That did the trick. Spending too much time configuring and setting up networks is my issue.